# Generating and reusing unique ID in C++

Tags: c++

I am working on a requirement where requests should have unique number from -2 to -101 inclusive, i.e., there are unique 100 requests at a time. If there are more than 100 requests at a given time then I should send error. Initially I have no requests. Once I sent requests I will take unique number say -2 , -3 and so on. Here requirement is that I may get command from client don't sent request to server for example -2 so I should delete this request and I should reuse this number for future request.

What is the best way to implement this in C++?

Also, I am not supposed to use Boost.

Comment: Use a std::list to hold available IDs. Initially you have all numbers in the list. After that add and remove whenever necessary.

Comment: @AtoMerZ Can you please give an example how to take this idea

Comment: If not Boost, how about the standard library then, like [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)? Or just an array `bool id_used[100]` which is set to `true` if an id is used?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask -- You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. _Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page._

Comment: @Evgeni I am curious to know how we can use std::bitset. Please give an example

Comment: @mah: I really don't see how that FAQ applies here. It's neither chatty nor open-ended. Granted, it's not the most complicated problem, but it's certainly not *not constructive*.

Comment: @bitmask, any question that is "what is the best way to..." is open ended. There might be some exceptions to this but they would only be items that do not have debate associated with them, and a simple reading of this page and the various options presented should be enough to convince you that debate is certainly on the table here.

Comment: @mah: No it's not. There is a difference between debate based on subjective opinion and proposing different solutions that can be objectively rated for efficiency. Just because a question gets several different answers, doesn't mean it's open-ended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to maintain a collection of unused ids at least. Additionally I would throw in a lookup table to verify that an id was handed out (for robustness). For both, I would suggest to use an `std::vector`, not a list.

First, store the unused collection in an `std::vector<int>`, which you can very easily initialise:

```
class IdStore {
  private:
    std::vector<int> unused;
    static int const MIN_ID = -101;
    static int const MAX_ID = -2;
  public:
    IdStore::IdStore()
    : unused(MAX_ID - MIN_ID + 1) {
      for (auto i = 0; i <= MAX_ID-MIN_ID; ++i) {
        unused[i] = i;
      }
    }
    int getId();
    void releaseId(int);
};
```

Additionally, you may want to keep track of the used ids, so you can verify if they were handed out; I'd use an `std::vector<bool> used;` member for that, which you can initialise simply with `used(MAX_ID - MIN_ID +1)` as its values will all default to `false` initially. Of course, you can make `used` also a `bitset` but note that this would require the distance from `MIN_ID` to `MAX_ID` to be known at compile time.

Handing out stuff is pretty simple from there:

```
int IdStore::getId() {
  if (unused.empty())
    throw "error"; // put something better here
  auto r = unused.back();
  used[r] = true;
  unused.pop_back();
  return MIN_ID + r;
}
```

And releasing them, also:

```
void IdStore::releaseId(int id) {
  if (id < MIN_ID || id > MAX_ID)
    throw "error"; // put something better here
  id -= MIN_ID;
  if (!used[id])
    throw "error"; // put something better here
  used[id] = false;
  unused.push_back(id);
}
```

Note that no reallocations take place! The vector will [keep its size](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/pop_back) and neither `getId` nor `releaseId` will require expensive calls to `malloc` or `free` contrary to an approach using a list.

Comment: Good point to use vector than list. Thanks for help.

Comment: Note  that `vector<bool>` is a [strange thing](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=98). Some aviod it, considering it evil.

Comment: @Evgeni: Thanks for the note. Yes, I know about the `std::vector<bool>` specialisation, but I think in this case it should be fine.

Comment: @bitmask Yes, people freak out about it a little too much, I think. But it may give you wierd errors that are hard to track, if youre unaware of the specialization. What I dont like though is that it incurrs a run-time overhead. For a static size Id consider `std::bitset` best, though

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on my `std::bitset` comment:

You can use the id as the index of the bitset and the value (`true/false`) as the availability of the id.

```
class IdStorage {
    const int N = 100;
   std::bitset<N> ids;

   bool allIdsUsed() { 
       return ids.all();
   }

   int getId() {
     if(allIdsUsed())
         throw "Error";

     for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i )
        if(ids.test(i))
            return i - 2;
   }

   void releaseId(int i) {
       ids.set(i + 2);
    }

}
```

Note that typed this in class, out of my head. Check the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)

Answer (score 1):

For only 100 numbers there may not be significant performance differences and you could use sets or arrays; plain old arrays like `id_used[100]` probably win in the performance measure.

If you need a scalable solution, try out having a "free-set" and a "used-set", with the free-set storing id's which are open for use, and the used-set with id's in use already. After using an id, store it back to the free set.

For a large enough ratio of allowed id's vs. concurrent uses, use only the "used-set", and use rejection sampling to find a free id:

```
do {
    id = generate_id();
} while(std::end != used_set.find(id));
```

Anyways, there is no definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't compiled it, but it should be something like this:

```
std::list<int> list;
for(int i=start; i<=end; ++i)
  list.insert(i);

//when get Id request
Id2send = list.first();
list.remove(list.first());

//when delete id request
list.remove(id);

//when add id request (this happens when an id is freed or other times)
list.add(id);
```